# Ребят выведет ли этот запрос конкретного сотрудника и количево переработанных часов, а то мне проверить негде

Tags: sql

SELECT * FROM operators WHERE time (employee = 'Кузнецов Анатолий') > 8 ;

Мне надо вывести кол-во переработанных часов при норме в 8 часов сотруднику Анатолий К.

Вот таблица [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В самом запросе ошибка

Comment: Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL? https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE-sql

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что этот ресурс не является личной тестовой площадкой участника

Comment: @АлексейШиманский По крайней мере, задающему вопрос можно подсказать, где он может протестировать свой запрос

Comment: @rotabor по секрету скажу:  в интернете есть поисковые системы!!! И уже более 20-ти лет..... А голова нужна не только для того, чтобы в неё кушать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский абсолютно согласен. Но подобных вопросов здесь много, и их количество не уменьшится - молодёжь-то подрастает. Видимо, в ВУЗах не учат пользоваться поисковыми системами, а надо бы.

Answer (score 0):

> а то мне проверить негде

1. https://dbfiddle.uk/
2. https://sqlize.online/
3. https://www.db-fiddle.com/
4. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/
5. https://sqliteonline.com/
6. https://sqltest.net/
7. .....

Comment: На 5 точек ничего не открыватся в браузере

Answer (score -2):

Правильный запрос:

```
SELECT Time-8 FROM operators WHERE Employee='Кузнецов Анатолий';
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/WGdZRbQ3

Возможно, понадобится использовать букву N: N'Кузнецов Анатолий'.

Comment: Ответ неправильный

Comment: @АлексейШиманский аргументируй и дай правильный ответ

Comment: Аргумент: читать надо внимательно!  Мне за тебя сделать? Нет спасибо.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вопрос: "Мне надо вывести кол-во переработанных часов при норме в 8 часов сотруднику Анатолий К." Ответ: 2. И что неправильно?

Comment: 'Анатолий К.' <> N'Кузнецов Анатолий'.

Comment: @Akina поймал, сдаюсь... :-) А то, что у автора в запросе написано "Кузнецов Анатолий", как бы ничего? Просто чел поленился фамилию полностью написать